Omit columns in ODATA V4 table retrieval
I am retrieving data from Dynamics NAV database via a webservice URL (ODATA V4) and including the $select option to get specific columns from the whole dataset. I do it in Power Query, either for Excel or PowerBI.
The problem though is that it is taking a hell-lot-of-time to download 1.4 MB of data, and at the same time, I get a table with all the columns, but only data in the selected columns. The rest of the columns show "error/null" values. Here's a snapshot of the results:

Seems like Power Query is making the full retrieval of data and then including only the values for the selected columns.
Is there anyway to let Power Query retrieve only the data of the selected columns?
Thanx in advance for your replies
I didn't try any solution because I couldn't find any

For that we need to see your power query query.

You can see it in the image, but nevertheless, here I put an example: "= OData.Feed("srv08mycompany:7048/DynamicsNAV110/ODataV4/Company('MYCOMPANY')/Productlist?$select=No, Description", null, [Implementation="2.0"])"

If you don't have any additional steps (in the right part of PQ window) then pq is not doing anything to add or remove columns.

I usually do this :
let

Source = OData.Feed("here put your link", null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
Table = Table.SelectColumns(Source{[Name="Your table name", Signature="table"]}[Data], {"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5"}) as table

in
Table

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Only-select-certain-columns-from-source/m-p/3696564/highlight/true#M1205531
